# Iterate over rows in a pandas dataframe and apply a lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has multiple columns, of which I am interested in a specific column that has a series of (1, or 0).
The logic that I want to perform is:

```
If (the current row is 1 and the next row is 0):
    count = count + 1
else :
    pass
df['NewCol'] = count
```

so, this is what I tried:

```
secCnt = 0 
def sectionCount(data):
    global secCnt
    if( (data[['secFlg']] == 0) and (data[['secFlg'].shift(-1)] == 1) ):
        secCnt = secCnt + 1 
    else:
        pass
    return secCnt


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df['SectionIndex'] = df.apply(sectionCount(df), axis=1)
```

I get the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

pI am new to pandas and am performing text extraction from a pdf file and am interested in finding out sections in the pdf file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need create boolean mask with comparing by `0` chaning by `&` (bitwise `AND`) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values and for count use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
np.random.seed(1213)

df = pd.DataFrame({'secFlg':np.random.randint(2, size=20)})

df['SectionIndex'] = ((df['secFlg'] == 0) & (df['secFlg'].shift() == 1)).cumsum()
print (df)
    secFlg  SectionIndex
0        0             0
1        1             0
2        1             0
3        1             0
4        0             1
5        0             1
6        0             1
7        0             1
8        0             1
9        1             1
10       0             2
11       0             2
12       0             2
13       0             2
14       1             2
15       1             2
16       1             2
17       0             3
18       1             3
19       0             4
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael. That works like a charm. Appreciate it my friend.